# weird ntfs-3g file created

Tags: file, ms-access, ntfs-3g

I have these weird files getting created, maybe someone could help me to work out what is happening. I'm dual-booting Windows 7 64-bit with ubuntu. I use MS Access a lot, and with one particular database, `catholic.mdb`. I occasionally see files getting created with names like this:

```
Catholic.mdb.ntfs-3g-0000000001
Catholic.mdb.ntfs-3g-0000000002     
Catholic.mdb.ntfs-3g-0000000003
```

These seem to be copies of my Access database - if I rename them, I can open them.

Googling for `ntfs-3g`, I found out that it is an NTFS driver for a non-Windows OS. Can anyone elaborate on what is causing this?

Thanks.